# Converting HTML to Output the body content to PDF

Tags: javascript, php, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I'm looking for a way to convert the content in the body of a HTML webpage into a pdf when a button/image (link) is clicked.

I looked into jspdf and mPDF, but those solutions aren't quite producing what I want.

I'd like the entire contents between the body tags to be what a user can save a s PDF - preferably with all of the styling (or as much as possible) preserved.

Shouldn't it be as simple as some code that essentially produces a screen shot of the page (although that might include unnecessary things such as URL bar, etc., and would likely render the PDF unsearchable in whatever storage set up that the user saves it to (but that isn't a priority right now)?

Summing up, I'm looking to have code (preferably some simple JS) that will achieve this goal of capturing content in the body tags, and saving it to a PDF at the user's command.

Thanks for attention and any insight :-)

Comment: How is the html created? Can you just generate a pdf version of it and the same time as generating the HTML and store it on the server? Then you just have to provide a link to the relevant PDF...

Comment: Hi Ella. No actually, the content comes from a Wordpress page that is generated by running a query on a select date, which brings up a list of events on that day (a calendar, where you can click "view all events" which then generates a page for that date with all of the events on there.

From there I'd like to be able to offer the user the ability to click an image or text that says "save to PDF", and converts the page into PDF.

Comment: If you use some sort of screen shot then the PDF will be an image.  Typically this means it's bigger, lower quality and can't be searched or text selected / read etc.  Since HTML and PDF are quite different your best results are typically to render from some source to both PDF.  Since you are trying to work from the HTML you have you will probably have to compromise on the PDF results.

Comment: Thanks. This is not a real concern, the page is mostly text.

Answer (score 0):

try using dompdf, you can download it from [here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf). If you get any error,

> 1. Create the dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/ directory
> 2. Download [this](https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib/releases) files
> 3. In the zip file, take the contents of the src/FontLib/ folder and paste that into dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/ folder

usage

```
require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
$html = "<html><body>HTML CODE
</body></html>";
$pdf = new DOMPDF();
$pdf->load_html($html);
$pdf->render();
$output = $pdf->output();
file_put_contents('output folder/file name.pdf', $output);
$pdf->stream('file name.pdf', array('Attachment' => 0));
```

Comment: you can change page size by using                                          `$paper_size = array(0,0,H,W);
$pdf->set_paper($paper_size);`

Comment: Many thanks. i'm going to start trying this right away, hopefully I'll return with a  success story and a vote :-)

Comment: let me know if you having any issues

Comment: Do I need to have the <HTML> tag in there, and other markup? Couldn't I just wrap this around my body tags in there already? It seems to me that that will cause a conflict with the pages <HTML> tag in there, as well as the body And come to think of it I probably only want a select number of DIV's or a certain container.

Comment: My concern is that I don't want to have to hard code HTML content in this i.e. -
$html = "<html><body>HTML CODE
</body></html>";

Instead, I want to render whatever is already there on the page without having to place that content in the variable.

Comment: try this make new html file and put your html code in it then put this code in your php fine where you will generate pdf `$html = file_get_contents('http://path to your html file');` this will get all content of your html file in $html variable

Comment: Thanks a lot..but I'm not sure what file that is. Could you clarify? Sorry for the ignorance :-\

Comment: i'm posting another answer with this solution, check that one

Comment: I did all of the above steps, but I am receiving:
Fatal error: Class 'Font' not found in /home/www/devious.runningh20.com/test-code/newest/dompdf/include/font_metrics.cls.php on line 346

but when I check the folder, it seems to be there. I'm not privy at all to what this error means. DO I go into the file and make edits? Or is it referring to a file that it claims isn't there (which I have verified that it is in fact there on the server, in the correct directory)

Comment: download this copy and extract in your directory http://www.4shared.com/rar/O3IyajP6ce/dompdf.html

Answer (score 0):

make one php file which will contain code that will generate PDF file

ex. demo.php, this file will contain below code

```
require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
$html = file_get_contents('test.html');
$pdf = new DOMPDF();
$pdf->load_html($html);
$pdf->render();
$output = $pdf->output();
file_put_contents('output folder/file name.pdf', $output);
$pdf->stream('file name.pdf', array('Attachment' => 0));
```

now make html file which will contain what you want to desplay you in your pdf file

ex. test.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

now, when you will open demo.php you will get pdf file with Hello text

Comment: make sure demo.php and test.html are in same directory

Comment: if you still get Fatal error: Class 'Font' not found error download fresh copy of dompdf from here http://www.4shared.com/rar/O3IyajP6ce/dompdf.html

Comment: Thanks again. I'm going to try this...but let me ask: is it possible to pass in a dynamic URL?

Comment: How do I achieve this? I tried to perhaps send you a private message or chat so SO doesn't keep sending me flags saying this is too long and possibly close up the question.